# Java client socket returns connection timedout exception

Tags: java, sockets

I am starting with JAVA Network programming. I have written a server class which uses ServerSocket to listen to port 3333. Following is the code snippet.

```
try {
            servSock = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
            //servSock.setSoTimeout(100000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Socket link = null; //Step 2.

        while(true){
            try {
                link = servSock.accept();
```

This works fine, in that the accept call blocks the program correctly.

But when I connect to the same port from the same machine through the client, using the below code

```
Socket link = new Socket();
link.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),3333), 50000);
```

It throws ConnectionTimedout after a while.

I am not able to connect to the server!. Please help someone.

Comment: try to print value of `InetAddress.getLocalHost()`. Also try replacing `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` with `localhost`

Comment: Wow that worked! :) was struggling with this for 3 hours now. Thanks a lot:)

Comment: What is the issue with InetAddress.getLocalhost? at least that is what is there in many tutorial texts.

Comment: i've mentioned the solution and explanation in an answer. Please accept it! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` with `localhost`.

The reason is that `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` actually returns the hostname of the machine, and the IP address associated with that hostname.

As mentioned [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18488982/634958):

> `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` doesn't do what most people think that it does. It actually returns the hostname of the machine, and the IP address associated with that hostname. This may be the address used to connect to the outside world. It may not. It just depends on how you have your system configured.

The javadoc for `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` is mentioned [**here**](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost%28%29).

Hope this helps.